# Spree installation issue : rake aborted! couldn't parse YAML at line 6 column 50

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I am trying to install the spree gem using the following instructions http://spreecommerce.com/resources/quick-start

I am getting following error on step 4.6(Populating the Database)

```
    $ rake db:bootstrap
    .....
    .......
    rake aborted! 
    couldn't parse YAML at line 6 column 50
    ....
    .....
```

I am using ruby 1.9.2p0, rails 3.0.3 and spree 0.40.2.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In boot.rb file inside config directory of my rails project home I added following and it worked.

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
```

I followed instruction from http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1002689

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an error in a YAML file, not surprisingly. It's likely a fixture used in the bootstrapping process.

You can always run `rake` with the `--trace` option to get a better sense of what it was trying to do. Have a look through your fixture files to see if any are invalid, especially at the position indicated.